# CSV to XML with modifications (XSLT?)

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I've been searching the forums for an answer to my problem, without any luck. I'm hoping you can help me. I have a simple CSV file that I need to convert to XML (that part's easy), but I need to modify it so that it contains sub elements. Example:

What I have:

```
<Unit>
        <UnitID>K000009107</UnitID>
        <DateLastModified>2003-06-23</DateLastModified>
        <Family>SAPOTACEAE</Family>
        <Genus>Pouteria</Genus>
        <Species>ferrugineo-tomentos</Species>
        <Identifier>Smith, J</Identifier>
        <StartMonth>05</StartMonth>
        <StartYear>1997</StartYear>
        <TypeStatus>Type</TypeStatus>
</Unit>
```

What I need:

```
<Unit>
    <UnitID>K000009107</UnitID>
    <DateLastModified>2003-06-23</DateLastModified>
    <Identification StoredUnderName="true">
        <Family>SAPOTACEAE</Family>
        <Genus>Pouteria</Genus>
        <Species>ferrugineo-tomentos</Species>
        <Identifier>Smith, J</Identifier>
        <IdentificationDate>
            <StartMonth>05</StartMonth>
            <StartYear>1997</StartYear>
        </IdentificationDate>
    <TypeStatus>Type</TypeStatus>
    </Identification>
</Unit>
```

I will need to do this modification on a large dataset. I'm guessing that XSLT will do the job, but I can't figure out how this would work. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? If you're using 2.0 and can post an example of the CSV, you could do the entire thing (conversion w/nesting) in one stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one way of doing this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="UnitID|DateLastModified"/>
   <Identification StoredUnderName="true">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "*[not(contains('|UnitID|DateLastModified|StartMonth|StartYear|TypeStatus|',
                    concat('|',name(),'|')))]"/>
    <IdentificationDate>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="StartMonth|StartYear"/>
    </IdentificationDate>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TypeStatus"/>
   </Identification>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Unit>
        <UnitID>K000009107</UnitID>
        <DateLastModified>2003-06-23</DateLastModified>
        <Family>SAPOTACEAE</Family>
        <Genus>Pouteria</Genus>
        <Species>ferrugineo-tomentos</Species>
        <Identifier>Smith, J</Identifier>
        <StartMonth>05</StartMonth>
        <StartYear>1997</StartYear>
        <TypeStatus>Type</TypeStatus>
</Unit>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Unit>
   <UnitID>K000009107</UnitID>
   <DateLastModified>2003-06-23</DateLastModified>
   <Identification StoredUnderName="true">
      <Family>SAPOTACEAE</Family>
      <Genus>Pouteria</Genus>
      <Species>ferrugineo-tomentos</Species>
      <Identifier>Smith, J</Identifier>
      <IdentificationDate>
         <StartMonth>05</StartMonth>
         <StartYear>1997</StartYear>
      </IdentificationDate>
      <TypeStatus>Type</TypeStatus>
   </Identification>
</Unit>
```

**This transformation can be shortened a little bit at the expense of losing flexibility:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="UnitID|DateLastModified"/>
   <Identification StoredUnderName="true">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "*[not(contains('|UnitID|DateLastModified|StartMonth|StartYear|TypeStatus|',
                    concat('|',name(),'|')))]"/>
    <IdentificationDate>
     <xsl:copy-of select="StartMonth|StartYear"/>
    </IdentificationDate>
    <xsl:copy-of select="TypeStatus"/>
   </Identification>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```